# cx_freeze AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I have been trying for quite some time now to make my Python program run on pc's that don't have python installed. I have issues because I'm using python 3.6.0. In this post I am going to discuss a method I got from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSoOwSqTSrs).

The first thing I did, was install Python 3.5 and create a virtualenv for it, which I activated. You can see how I did that [on the post I made earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188424/how-to-let-others-run-your-python-program-without-installing-python). After I activated the environment, I used this command in cmd in the python 3.5 environment: `pip install cx_Freeze`. It got installed with no errors. Then I made this `setup.py` file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='vkv',
  version='0.1',
  description='Berekent de wortels van een vkv',
  executables = [Executable('vkv.py')])
```

The python file that I want to turn into a `.exe` file is called `vkv.py`. The `vkv.py` file and the `setup.py` file are both the only 2 files on this path: `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Code\Python testing\distr`.

Ok so now I only have to enter `setup.py build` in the command line in order to make the `.exe` file. But when I do that, I get a bunch of lines, with an error on the last line:

```
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'
```

Here is a screenshot of it: [image]

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Is it something in the `setup.py` file, is it not setting up the virtualenv correctly? And does anyone know what this error means and how I can fix it?

Comment: Just a little note: the description in the setup.py file is Dutch, but I don't think that it should matter much, since it's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with an version of `cx_freeze` that has a bug that manifests itself for versions larger than `3.5.2`, this issue has already been reported [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/225/cxfreeze-module-dis-has-no-attribute) and [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-requests/100/fixed-issue-225/diff).

In short, a small change was introduced in `Python 3.5.2` that `cx_freeze` failed to catch, now a check is made to work smoothly.

In short, you'll need to update `cx_freeze`, you could either try `pip install -U cx_freeze` or get the source for it.

p.s Using Python 3.6 right now probably isn't the best idea since quite some changes were made and bugs might take a while to be caught and fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and edit of the post. Which python version should I use? I have currently installed 3.6.0 and 3.5.0. Do I need the latest version of 3.5?